# Rackspace as cloud storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, cloud, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to set up rack space for cloud storage using carrier-wave for image uploads. From all the documentation i can find it seems like i need an initializer file. Something like this

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
:provider           => 'Rackspace',
:rackspace_username => 'xxxxxx',
:rackspace_api_key  => 'yyyyyy',
:rackspace_region   => :ord                # optional, defaults to :dfw
}
config.fog_directory = 'name_of_directory'
end
```

My question is where do i put these settings within a rails application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails convention is to put such files in config/initializers. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files